# Is there any node module for application lock using pattern lock?

Tags: react-native

I have using **react-native-smart-gesture-password** node module to create a pattern lock application .But i have no idea about how to lock my phone to use my application any one help me to how integrate the app lock

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this lib: 
https://github.com/prscX/react-native-lock-screen

Usage

```
import RNLockScreen from 'react-native-lock-screen';

<RNLockScreen type={RNLockScreen.Type.Pin} mode={RNLockScreen.Mode.Capture} onCapture={lock => {
  }} onVerified={() => {

  }}
  lock={'123'}
/>
```